# how to read in file that contains char, int and white space into linked list

Tags: c++, list, file-io, linked-list

Hi I have problem when I read in file that contains white space into the linked list

Here's the read in file:

a 19
, 11
m 4
  8
b 23
q 33

Here's my code

```
struct story
{
  char letter;
  int number;
  story *next;
};

int main()
{
  story *head = NULL; // list head pointer                                           
  ifstream inFile;

  char letter;
  int num;                                                           

  // read file                                                                         
  inFile.open(FILENAME.c_str());
  if(inFile.fail())
    cout << "Error..." << endl;
  while (inFile >> letter){
    cout << letter << " " ;
    inFile >> num ;
    cout << num << " ";                                                                                                  
  }
  inFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

the output: a 19 , 11 m 4 8 0

The program skip the space while reading the file. and it stop reading file. getline()function would help to read, but I want to store char and int separately since this is a linked list project.

Comment: What is your problem? In any case, note that you do not verify if `num` was read successfully: you are probably better off to use `while (inFile >> letter >> num) { ... }`. If you want to disable skipping of spaces, you can use `inFile >> std::noskipws` and then skip whitespace as needed using `inFile >> std::ws`.

Comment: Also, your file does not follow the pattern you are using to read from it (iterations of a char then an int). `a 19 , 11 m 4 8 b 23 q 33` should be read in as char, int, char, int, char, int, **int**, char, int, char, int.

Comment: You need to account for the semicolon, and skip it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl :i tried to do while(inFile>>noskipws>>letter>>num){...} it doesn't read anything

Comment: @user3923936: well, that's hardly a surprise! If you don't want the input operators skip leading whitespace, you'll need to do it yourself. That is, the expresssion will read a letter but fail to read a number because the next character seen is a space! You complained that spaces are automatically skipped and I told you how to disable this (for details I'm sure you consulted the manual on what `std::noskipws` does). You also didn't clarify what you problem is. Of course, in your sequence you don't alternate between something and integer: `b` will be read as an `int` which will fail.

Comment: I really have no idea what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

file should be binary:

```
outFile.open(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);

inFile.open(FILENAME.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
```

you should read/write records of at least 5 bytes, depending the alignment. 
it is easy to read /write the whole struct.

read:

```
story *s=new story;
inFile.read(s,sizeof(s));
s->next=NULL;
```

Use `write` to write the file.